# rails ajax controller won't call javascript

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I'm trying to create a new comment to a video

**show.html.erb** in videos view

```
   <h5>New Comment</h5>

    <%= render 'comments/form' %>

  <div class = "show-comments">
    <% if @video.comments.size > 0 %>
      <h5>Comments</h5>

      <% for comment in @video.comments %>
        <div class = "well">
        <p><%= comment.content %></p>
        <small><%= comment.updated_at %></small>
        <% if comment.user_id == current_user.id %>
            <p align="right"><%= link_to 'delete', comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
        <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>

  </div>
```

**_form.html.erb** in comments view

```
  <%= form_for [@video, Comment.new], remote: true do |f| %>
      <p><%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 3 %></p>
      <p><%= f.submit %></p>
    <% end %>
```

**create method in comments_controller.rb**

```
 def create
    @video = Video.find(params[:video_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])

    current_user.comments << @comment
    @video.comments << @comment

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save

        format.html { redirect_to @video, notice: 'Comment was successfully added.' }
        format.js

      end
    end
  end
```

**create.js.coffee.erb** file

```
new_comment = $('<p><%= @comment.content %></p>')
$(".show-comments").prepend(new_comment)
```

When I click the submit comment button, it should call the javascript and post a new comment but it doesn't.

Here is an error message

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost:3000/videos/51adc1ae25e218d5f6000001/comments
POST http://localhost:3000/videos/51adc1ae25e218d5f6000001/comments 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template comments/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your file to `create.js.coffee`.

It should still render erb although it is not written in the file extension.

Let me know if it helped you